# Given $K$ an ordered field, if, for every $a\in K$ there's a sequence of rationals $(a_{n})$ with limit $a$, then K is archimedean

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I'm trying to clarify some doubts that I have regarding this proof. In one step, from the definition of limit, the writter says:

$|a_{n}-a|<1 \implies a<a_n+1$.

I can see that you can go from the first inequality to the second one by "expanding" the absolute value:

$|a_{n}-a|<1 \implies -1<a_n-a<1\implies a-1<a_n<a+1$ and using only the first of this inequalities, you get $a<a_n+1$. From here, the writter goes on to say that since $a_n+1$ is rational, we can find a natural such that $a<n$.

But why we need to use that first inequality? Can't we just say that $a<a+2$ and there's a natural such that $a+2<n$, or since $a$ is any element of $K$, it is not necessary rational?

Another question: Can we use any $\epsilon$ for $|a_n-a|<\epsilon$, and impose that $\epsilon$ to be rational? Or is it better to use 1?

Comment: When you say "field" do you mean "ordered field"?

Comment: I don't see why you can always find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a + 2 < n$. In fact, $\forall a \in K$ $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a +2 < n$ is exactly same statement as $\forall a \in K$ $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a < n$ via the substitutions $a \mapsto a + 2$ and $a \mapsto a - 2$.

Comment: For your second question, I think yes. The proof should work as long as $a_n + \epsilon$ is rational.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown edited, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see that the part you are having difficulties with is the counterintuitive idea of a non-Archimedean ordered field. A field $K$ is Archimedean if and only if for all $a\in K$, there exists some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a<n1_K$. Here, $1_K$ stands for the multiplicative identity of the field $K$. On the other side, $K$ is a non-Archimedean ordered field if and only if there exists some $a\in K$ such that $a>n1_K$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

In the proof of the theorem of your question, you cannot claim a priori that for $a\in K$ there is some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $a+2<n1_K$, because you do not know that the field $K$ is Archimedean yet. That is why you need to use the hypothesis (approximation by rational numbers). In other words, in your doubt lies the relevance of the theorem.

This may be clearer if you see a concrete example of a non-Archimedean ordered field.
Consider $\mathbb{R}[x]$, the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$. Define an order on $\mathbb{R}[x]$ as follows: for constant polynomials consider the order of $\mathbb{R}$.

For $p=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, with $a_n\neq0$, put $p>0$  whenever $a_n>0$. Now, in the field of rational functions $\mathbb{R}(x)=\{p/q:p,q\in\mathbb{R}[x], q\neq0\}$ consider the order defined as follows: $p/q>0$ whenever $pq>0$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Here, for all $f,g\in\mathbb{R}(x)$, $f<g$ whenever $0<g-f$.

This field is an extension of $\mathbb{R}$ as ordered field where $a<x^2$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $\mathbb{R}(x)$ is a non-Archimedean ordered field.

Thus, according with the (contrapositive of the) theorem, there exists an element $f\in\mathbb{R}(x)$ that is not the limit of any sequence of rational numbers. In fact, from the inequaly $a<x^2$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$, we see that $|x^2-a|=x^2-a>\varepsilon$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and for all $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}$, $\varepsilon>0$.

Regarding your second question, you are right. You can use any $\varepsilon$ as long as it is rational.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea with the proof is that, even if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a$, those $a_n$'s may be all *less* than $a$. Thus, we add something constant, positive and rational (e.g. $1$ or a rational $\varepsilon\gt 0$) to get another sequence with a limit *greater* than $a$. For instance, if $b_n=a_n+1$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=a+1$ and $b_n$'s are all rational. Thus, some $b_n\gt a$. If $b_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ then $p_n\gt q_n a\ge a$.

Note: The author doesn't explicitly invoke a new sequence $b_n$, but I think their proof would be more comprehensible if they did; what they did seems to boil down to the same thing.